# How to write a ping to a text file using VBS

Tags: scripting, vbscript, ping, writetofile

If I am using VBS to run some CMD commands, in this example ping, how could I write the command to a text file using VBS not DOS?

```
Set objCmdTest = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Set Output = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\vbs\test.txt",8,true)

Output.WriteLine (objCmdTest.run ("ping failboat"))
Output.WriteLine (objCmdTest.run ("ping 8.8.8.8"))
```

So this is what I'm working with however what happens is; The script runs, the file is made, 2 command prompts open to run the pings and finally the text inside the file reads:

```
0
0
```

When I'd much prefer it to have the ping output.

FYI: Please don't offer suggestions that require me to use DOS for the writing, I'd like to see how VBS can do what I need for multiple reasons, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instruction `Output.WriteLine (objCmdTest.run ("ping failboat"))` will write the *return value* of the `Run` method to the output file. If you want to append the command output to an output file you have to either redirect the output in the command:

```
objCmdTest.run "%COMSPEC% /c ping failboat >>C:\vbs\test.txt", 0, True
```

or use [`Exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a) instead of `Run`:

```
Set ping = objCmdTest.Exec("ping failboat")
Do While ping.Status = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
Output.WriteLine ping.StdOut.ReadAll
```

Answer (score 1):

WScript.Shell's run method returns the process's exit code. In order to get access to an application's output, you need to use the [exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method instead, and use the object that returns to get access to the process's standard output through its [StdOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbxxzwb5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property.